# Calling a method from within a synchronized method

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrentmodification

I'm facing a strange problem which has made me wonder what exactly happens in a synchronized method. Let's say there is a method

```
synchronized public void example(){
     //...code
     int i=call(); //calling another method
     //...do something with i 
}
```

Now while the call() method is being executed, can another object enter this synchronized example() method? So when the call() returns, there might be some ConcurrentModificationException? What to do in order to avoid problems?

Comment: Many years late, but ReentrantReadWriteLock should do what you're hoping to do, I think.

Answer (score 3):

No it can't. A synchronized method is basically the same as:

```
public void example(){
  synchronized(this){
    //do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: so even if i leave the synchronized method and then return back, it will be like one whole big synchronized method? Calls to external methods won't cause any problems?

Comment: The reason I'm trying to be so sure is that, then the problem in my program is probably because of some other thing, which I have to find out.thanks.

Comment: No, they don't cause any problem. If they would, what could you do in a synchronized block? Any meaningful task involves calling some method.

Comment: @aps Even though the method is `synchronized`, what's really happening is that the monitor on the invoking object is being entered when the method starts, and then exited when the method returns. Whatever happens between those two points doesn't affect the status of the monitor, and so even external methods won't compromise that.

Answer (score 3):

Note that in this example, if `call()` isn't private or is called from somewhere else in the class, someone else can interrupt what you *think* is an entirely synchronous process.

```
synchronized void a(){
    println 'hello'
    b();
    println 'world'
}

void b(){

}
```

If you expect "everything that a does to be guarded by synchronized", then if b has any side-effects at all, that guarantee is lost if methods other than `synchronized void a` call `b`.

Comment: I get your point.so what should I do in that case? make b synchronized so that no interrupts occur?

Comment: If `b` is only ever called from a, you're okay. To be safe, any entry point (public, protected, default) method into a class can be synchronized. That way, you are in-fact guaranteeing that only single thread can use the object at a time. Also make sure you don't directly manipulate public, protected, or default variables, as you can get hosed in the exact same way as the method setup.

Comment: For a very elaborate and teeth-grinding treatment of the topic, check out the SCJP 6 study book. http://www.amazon.com/SCJP-Certified-Programmer-Java-310-065/dp/0071591060

Comment: @Greg: I see that you're trolling my answers with downvotes, and the automated stackexchange auditter will also.

Comment: Its hardly trolling if I offer a VALID explanation for each downvote. You can't deny the code is wrong here and doesn't even attempt proper syntax.

Comment: I see you're not familiar with other JVM based languages, then, or prototyping of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

When a thread enters a Synchronized method a lock occurs, the lock doesn't release until that method returns, which would be after your call to `call()`.

Here is a good article on locks and synchronization:
http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html