# Will synchronized method lock all methods within it?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am trying to understand what happens if I mark a method as synchronized and what happens to the calls from within that method. My SyncClass is called from an external webservice. These webservice calls can happen any number of times. 
Example:

```
//Webservice talks to this class.
class SyncClass {
    public synchronized void syncMethod() {
        Service service = new Service();
        service.serviceBlock();
      }
}

class Service{

   public void serviceBlock(){
    doManyThings(){
    // validation
    // service logic
    SaveService save = new SaveService();
    save.saveMe();
   }
}

}

class SaveService {

 public void saveMe(){
  //many operations
  public methodA();
  public methodB();
  public methodC();
}
}
```

What happens if there are calls coming from within my application directly invoking the methodA(), methodB(), methodC() etc. These methods can be called from other places. If the syncMethod has acquired a lock from the webservice, will it lock these 3 methods as well?

Comment: Using `synchronized` on a method doesn't make other methods thread safe. It means that `syncMethod` will be thread safe, while `saveMe`, `methodA`, `methodB` and `methodC` will not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calling a method from within a synchronized method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6961848/calling-a-method-from-within-a-synchronized-method)

Answer (score 3):

More precisely, the `syncMethod` will lock the instance (of `SyncClass`). Any `synchronized` method or block will block if it's applied to the same instance. In your case, `Service` and `serviceBlock` are unrelated to `SyncClass`, so no, it will not block.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no.
Lock will only be acquired for syncMethod()

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `synchronized` here means that calls to `syncMethod` will be serialized (one thread at a time).

Objects that you create inside of `syncMethod` are not guarded automatically. So if you expose those objects to the outside code, then they can be mutated concurrently.

At the same time, in **your** example `service` object is not visible outside of `syncMethod`. And `save` object is not visible outside of `serviceBlock`. So, there is no way for `methodA` to be called from the outside. In this case, no further synchronization is needed.